# Is there a way to export my adblock settings from Chrome to Safari?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, adblock

I am using AdBlock in chrome: https://getadblock.com/gplus/v2.6-released/ and I have several custom div's I have hid in many web pages I use.

I want to switch to Safari from Chrome.

Is there any way to import these custom hidden divs for this Extension?

Comment: What do you mean 'div'? If you mean your own filters, edit them as raw text, copy them and then paste them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old - just sharing since related/if helpful.

[**Copying Adblock Plus settings from one Chrome browser to another**](https://gist.github.com/7c547495d59f126b48bf57c6dbd26a89)